# Are there deals for multiple domestic flights in Argentina?

Tags: air-travel, budget, luggage, argentina, domestic-travel

I'm planning to visit Argentina for 1 month in January and will most likely be flying 4 domestic flights. (Buenos Aires → Ushuaia, Ushuaia → El Calafate, El Calafate → Bariloche, Bariloche → Buenos Aires).

Is there any kind of "package" deal for multiple flights like this, or do I instead buy each flight separately?

Comment: I thought there was already a question covering the topic. While it goes beyond only domestic flights, Aerolineas has an offer including supposedly cheaper domestic flights if you buy an international flight : http://www.aerolineas.com.ar/en-EU/VuelosBaratos/VisiteArgentina

Comment: How much taxes do I add to those prices? the flight from Ushuaia to El Calafate is much cheaper through expedia.com (~$140 taxes incl.), the rest are slightly more expensive but include taxes. From what I see, baggage limitations for domestic flights with Aerolineas are 15kg whereas if you buy the Visit Argentina flights the limitations are like with the international flights. what's the best way to book those domestic flights ?

Comment: Have you considered taking the bus instead? They are way more comfortable than the flights.

Comment: This is our honeymoon and we're short on time, We can't waste it on days of bus rides

Answer (score 1):

January is summer time in Argentina and it is the high season.
Flight prices will be more expensive than any other time of the year.
If you flight from Buenos Aires to Ushuaia, you could consider flying with Lan Argentina instead of Aerolineas Argentinas.

If you try to book online with a non-Argentinean credit card on Aerolineas Argentinas, suddenly the prices go up by hundreds of Euros.

I think it would be very useful if you can contact an Argentinean travel agency that you can trust to find out the prices in Argentinean pesos for you.

Alternatively, partner airlines (like Air France) let you book internal flights (AEP to Ushuaia).

Answer (score 1):

I actually did use their deal for this, it's now called the "[Visit Argentina](http://www.aerolineas.com.ar/en-us/cheap_flights/visit_argentina)" pass (originally their "Argentina Travel" deal).

We used it for four flight legs. The main problem is that they use a hub and spoke model, with most flights flying in and out of Buenos Aires. So while we wanted to go from El Calafate to Iguazú Falls, to Salta, we had to go El Calafate to Buenos Aires, to Iguazú Falls, to Buenos Aires, to Salta.  Each of those counts as a leg.

It's valid for 3-12 legs, and can be combined with their [South American pass](http://www.aerolineas.com.ar/en-us/cheap_flights/south_american_pass), for flights to other countries in the region.

[My blog post about when we chose to use the "Argentina Travel" deal (now known as the "Visit Argentina" pass](http://www.marksmayo.com/2010/07/16/a-sudden-change-of-plans/) - we used it for four legs, from El Calafate, to Buenos Aires, to Iguazú Falls, to Buenos Aires, to Salta.  However, we actually got a refund in the end on the Salta leg as they had flight cancellations, and we had to bus instead.

Comment: Found out about this deal after we arrived in Argentina -- bummer! Definitely the best deal for flexible travel as both AA and LAN still have the antiquated "One Way ticket costs more than a return" policy.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [despegar](http://despegar.com.ar) to book tickets and hotels, you could probably find better deals there in comparison to Expedia.